# Batch processing in Camtasia Studio or others

Tags: video, post-production

I am making some tutorial videos for which I need to have same production setting. Like
1. Noise cancellation. Camtasia studio has a option where it automatically cancels the noise. 
2. Intro and Conclusion. I want to add some intro slide/video before the starting of the video and same with the conclusion. Though I can do it individually it will take quite significant time adding to each and than rendering.

Is there an options where by default I can have these actions performed on my every video and batch process them. Or if some other software which can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

so Batch processing is very possible in Camtasia Studio.
Here are my personal step-by-setp instrcutions:

1. Import the videos you wish to Bacth Render into a new Camtasia Studio project file.
2. Add the first video to the Timeline and then save it as a Camtasia Studio Project file.
3. Remove that video from the timeline and import the other video you imported onto the timeline and **save it as a different Camtasia Studio Project file.**
   (You can repeat these steps as many times as you need to to have all videos you wish to Batch render)
4. Find the 'Tools' tab and hover the cursor down to 'sharing' and a 'Batch production' should be avaliable to click. Click it.
5. Click on the 'Add files/projects' button and select the files you made earlier.
6. Click "Next" after you have selected all the videos you wish to Batch Render.
7. Choose a preset from the top drop down menu.
8. Clcik "Next".
9. You can choose the location the rendered videos will be saved to and if you want to have each video into sub-folders.
10. Click on the "Finish" button.
11. Your videos should be rendering.

I hope I helped and hope you have a nice day :)